# Create expandable rows in ng2-table

Tags: angular, bootstrap-table

I am trying to think of a way or find an example of how to create a expandable/collapsable row in [ng2-table](http://valor-software.com/ng2-table/) for Angular2. Preferably, I would just like to have a button for each row, clicking on it will expand the corresponding row showing its details in a custom component, not just another set of rows. Does anyone know an easy to go about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an accordion like feature?

http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/accordion

For example: You could use this accordion feature to iterate through your list. Then click on an element of the list to open it which is where you could put your ng2-table.